# How we call an struct inside of another struct as embedded?

Tags: go, struct

Why we don't call person field as `embedded`?

```
“type user struct {
 name  string
 email string
}
 
type admin struct {
 person user  // NOT Embedding
 level  string
}”
```

But in other cases like below we call it embedded:

```
“type user struct {
 name  string
 email string
}
 
type admin struct {
 user  // Value Semantic Embedding
 level  string
}”
```

What I think is that `person` is also embedded like value/pointer semantic embedding. What I'm missing here?

Comment: Value/pointer semantics has nothing to do with *embedding*, do not conflate the two. A struct is composed of a *"sequence of named elements, called fields, each of which has a name and a type. Field names may be specified **explicitly (IdentifierList)** or **implicitly (EmbeddedField)**."* So `admin.person` in example #1 is a plain field, `admin.user` in example #2 is an embedded field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's how the [Go language specification](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.17_spec#Struct_types) defines it:

> A field declared with a type but no explicit field name is called an *embedded field*.

I can see how the term "embedded" would be confusing. After all, named and unnamed fields end up with the same memory layout, "embedded" into the parent struct. "Anonymous field" might have been a better name for it, but that's not the name that the Go language designers chose.

Comment: btw the term "anonymous" used to be used for embedded fields, and [remnants](https://pkg.go.dev/go/types@go1.18.4#Var.Anonymous) of that can still be found in the public api, but it's been "superseded" now, and I believe any new addition added to the code base is expected to use the term "embedded".

Answer (score 0):

With the first code you can't treat an `admin` object as a `user` object, like using member access or type assertion. This also affects how an embedding struct satisfies `interface`s.

For example, the following code works with proper embedding, but not a simple member struct:

```
var a admin

a.name = "asdfg"

u := a.(user)
```